Multiplication fractions related to trig identities
Using Double Angle Trig Identities:
Find exactly $\sin v = \frac{2}{5}$, $90^{\circ} < v < 180^{\circ}$.
$\sin v = 2\sin v\cos v$
Attempt:
$\cos^2(v) + \sin^2(v) = 1$
$\cos^2(v) + \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^2 = 1$
$\cos^2(v) + \frac{4}{25} = 1$
$\cos^2(v) = 1 - \frac{4}{25}$
$1 - \frac{4}{25} = \frac{25}{25} - \frac{4}{25} = \frac{25 - 4}{25} = \frac{21}{25}$
$\sqrt{\cos^2(v)} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{21}{25}}$
$\cos v = \pm \sqrt{\frac{21}{25}}$
$2\sin v\cos v = 2(2/5)(- \sqrt{\frac{21}{25}})$
$\frac{4}{5}(- \sqrt{\frac{21}{25}})$
When I hit: $2(\frac{4}{5})$ = I get $\frac{4}{5}$ on my calculator. Can I just distribute by multiplication 5 to make it $\frac{4}{25}$. Because the denominator has to be $25$ to put them together and get numerator $4\sqrt{21}$.

@YvesDaoust, yes, because I have had sleepless nights and I am not thinking clearly.

If I understand correctly, your question is: find $\sin(2v)$ if $\sin v=2/5$ and $90^°<v<180^°$. Your computations are correct, you found $\cos v=-\sqrt{\frac{21}{25}}$ hence:
$$\sin(2v)=2\sin v\cos v=2\cdot\frac25\cdot\left(-\sqrt{\frac{21}{25}}\right)=-\frac45\frac{\sqrt{21}}5=-\frac4{25}\sqrt{21} $$
